# training machine learning model to not classify wrong inputs or empty inputs

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, svm

I have a dataset as shown below (just shown here only 6 rows). I have like 700 rows and I want to classify them into categories like 9887, 8413, etc. The problem is that the model is also classifying totally unrelated inputs like, "Christmas Tree", "New Year", "Nike is a good sports brand", into one of the given categories 9887 or 8413, etc. I want when the input is totally unrelated or empty "", it should classify them into a category 0000.

```
personInfo                               personID

alicia is from unitedStates              9887
alicia likes to do Yoga                  9887
cooking is one of the hobby of alicia    9887
sam is from Brazil                       8413
sam father is a doctor                   8413
In free time, sam prefers hiking         8413
```

My code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['personInfo'], df['personId'], random_state = 0)
count_vect = CountVectorizer().fit(X_train)
X_train_counts = count_vect.transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts) 
classificationModel = LinearSVC().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train) 
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(classificationModel, open(filename, 'wb'))
#data_to_be_predicted="alicia has a sister in texas"
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.predict(count_vect.transform([data_to_be_predicted]))
print(result)
```

Here is one input-output:

```
input: "alicia has a sister in texas"
output: 9887
```

Now for the below input I want the model to classify as 0000 because is not related but it is classifying it as either 9887 or 8413 or some other given category

```
input: "christmas tree"
expected output: 0000

input: " "
expected output: 0000
```

Comment: You have to teach the model to classify those inputs. Add mappings from bad inputs to 0000 in your training set - your model can't learn to do something if it's never seen anything like it before.

Comment: But the bad input code be anything. "Christmas Tree", "New Year", "Nike is a good sports brand" are some examples which I have given, I do not have a list of bad inputs, so how can I train it?

Comment: I agree with @Primusa. It is better to add some bad data and map to 0000. Also, you may use the probability value to check the confidence level for the prediction. By adding a cutoff condition on probability, you may achieve better results.

Comment: @MohanaRao Thanks for the feedback. I am not specific to 0000, what I meant was when the model gets any input on which it is not been trained then it should give output like 0000 or "Unknown" or "I don't know" instead of making some wrong prediction out of the available categories
1. The bad data is not specific, it could be anything, so how would I know what all bad data could be.
2. May I know how to do that confidence level  check that you are suggesting?